# Do we have DD4T 1.31 Provider for SDL Web 8?

Tags: web8, dd4t, migration

I have seen lot of links which say DD4T 1.31 supports SDL web 8 (Inprocess) but  i am not able to figure out which provider to use as we don't have any SDL web 8 provider in DD4T 1.31.

Can i use same SDL tridion 2013 provider with SDL web 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL Web 8 in-process CD APIs are fully compatible with Tridion 2013 SP1.

So, you can just use the DD4T Provider for Tridion 2013 SP1. You only need some so-called *assembly binding redirects* because the assembly versions are different.

For an example of *assembly binding redirects*, see: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Web.config